# How to add button to open url with parameter in datatables Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, datatable, datatables, laravel-8

I have some data shown in my datatable view, I want to add button to each data to open detail page which can show more detail information

```
public function Task(Request $request)
    {    

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = DB::table('posts')
                ->where('jabatan', Auth::user()->jabatan)
                ->select('user_id', 'name', DB::raw('count(user_id) as total'))
                ->selectRaw('SUM(status = "Selesai") as selesai')
                ->selectRaw('count(user_id) - SUM(status = "Selesai") as belum')
                ->groupBy('name')
                ->groupBy('user_id')->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
              
                    $btn = ' <a href="{{route(\'detail.index\',$row->user_id)}}"data-original-title="Detail" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 btn-sm detailProduct"><span class="fas fa-eye"></span></a>';

                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->make(true);
        }

        return view('task.Task');
    }
```

the button can appear in my datatable, but it will open %7B%7Broute('detail.index',$row->user_id)%7D%7D ,

If in a html table I can use `<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('detail.index',$post->id) }}">Show</a>`

how to make the button to open /detail in url? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your in already in php so don't use `{{ }}` blade syntax use

```php
$btn = '<a href="'.route("detail.index",['detail'=>$row->user_id]).'"data-original-title="Detail" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 btn-sm detailProduct"><span class="fas fa-eye"></span></a>';
```

Comment: The button will redirect to ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail?6``` how to redirect to ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/6```

Comment: add your `web.php` route so i can tell u

Comment: Im using ```Route::resource('detail', DetailController::class);```